# Difference between tags [medical] and [healthcare]?

Tags: discussion, tags

- [healthcare](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/healthcare): 36 questions, tag wiki written by me a few weeks ago.
- [medical](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medical): 18 questions, no tag wiki.

Could an expert please tell us the difference between the two?
Or should it be just a single tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think they should be a single tag, as medical (also to seperate from healthcareapi)

Comment: I think the distinction between the two is very blurred in most people's minds. I would support this merge.